# How do I ensure that the last item in a RecyclerView is aligned to the bottom of the window when the list is not scrollable?

Tags: android

I want to ensure that the last item in my RecyclerView is aligned to the bottom of the window when the content isn't scrollable, like so:
[aligned to bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDenE.png)

I also need the last item to append to the bottom of the list and scroll with it if it is scrollable, like so:
[scrolling with RecyclerView content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISRdb.png)

I am not necessarily looking for line-by-line code on how to do this. I am looking for the right approach. I have explored the option of using a separate "clone" view outside of the RecyclerView for the first case, but I want to keep the behaviour of a ReyclerView item so that didn't work out. Open to suggestions.

Comment: I believe this would be a custom LayoutManager.  Possibly could just be extended from the LinearLayoutManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html